# Help, cannot how to run unsafe

Tags: c#-4.0

How to run csc /unsafe *.cs

```
using System;

class UnsafeCode
{
      unsafe static void Main()      
      {
        int count = 99;
        int* p;
        p = &count;
        Console.WriteLine("Initial value of count is " + *p);
        *p = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("New value of count is " + *p);
      }
}
```

Error 1 Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe C:\Documents and Settings\Eddy  Ho\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\608-UnsafeCode-Errors\608-UnsafeCode-Errors\Program.cs 5 26 608-UnsafeCode

Comment: I don't know C#, so I can't help you answer your question, but I suspect that more people would be interested in helping if you'd coherently explain what the problem is, instead of just posting some code and an error message. Also, when you post code, make sure to format it properly so that Stack Overflow can make it readable for us: see http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It's a command line argument.

You use the Visual Studio command prompt and simply type it out.

You can also set this in the IDE, by going to the properties of the project, and in the `Build` tab select `Allow unsafe code` checkbox. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx).